# Try to access sites data using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I tried to fetch same URL via google script & Oauth playground.....In playground it works properly and give status 200 OK..But with google script , it gives invalid argument error......Give me some suggestion

URL='https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainname/siteName/-/template|-template
'

Code :

```
 var base = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/';
     var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('sites', base);
     fetchArgs.method = 'GET';

 var url=https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainname/siteName/-/template|-template'
       var resultOfSiteWebPages=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)
```

Gives error in UrlFetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a encoding issue. The oAuth playground probably encodes the url for you and `UrlFetch` doesn't. Try this:

```
var resultOfSiteWebPages = UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodeURI(url), fetchArgs);
```

Comment: @Rishi You're welcome. Since you're new here... you should mark an answer as accepted when you feel to got a good one.